# OnTime Alternative?

Tags: project-management, ontime

I've recently begun working with a new software development firm. One of the things I would like to do is introduce a software management tool to collectively group the project development efforts within a single source.

I've traditionally used [OnTime](http://www.axosoft.com/products/ontime.aspx) and my initial reaction was to introduce it within the new company as well. However, the pricing is a little too high for the Professional version at this point.

Can anyone offer any real alternatives which offer both Feature / Defect / Project management with easy reporting and dashboards? Basically I'm looking for an OnTime alternative which has been proven through use.

Thanks,

Brian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are tons of options here. [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) (free), [Mingle](http://studios.thoughtworks.com/mingle-agile-project-management) (pay), [FogBugz](http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBUGZ/) (free to try and other select uses), [Rally](http://www.rallydev.com/)et al.

It depends on which set of features you value most and how your development process works. I personally enjoy FogBugz, have used Mingle professionally, and like Trac on the hobby stuff where I've used it. I've also used TeamTrack, but I wasn't a fan. Rally is award-winning, but it was never the best fit for my thought process.

Here's [Wikipedia's list of project-management software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_project_management_software).

Comment: I thought that FogBugz was a defect / bug management tool rather than a software management tool. I'm looking for something more akin to OnTime whereby every step of the project is captured and maintained rather than the outcomes of the development. We're currently using Kayako as our support tool so the defect management is probably the least important aspect of the software from our perspective.

Have I got the wrong end of the stick with FogBugz?

Comment: Most decent bugtracking software provides feature planning, roadmapping, task assignment, etc.

The difference between an "issue" and a "feature" is largely semantic, so it is definitely worth looking at other solutions to see what they might offer.

Comment: As I said, it's largely a matter of taste. FogBugz works with cases (I think that's their term; it's been a while) and those can be defects or features. In particular, the evidence-based scheduling is stellar for projecting when your current set of features will ship so you can cut features or adjust timelines, etc. It also has a wiki to capture things like requirements, specs, etc. It can integrate with version control systems. Overall, it's lightweight and pretty flexible. If you prefer a heavier process, it might not be your cup of tea, but it's definitely more than bug-tracking.

Answer (score 2):

We really like [fixx](http://hedgehoglab.com/products/fixx/), it provides pretty much everything we need, and everyone picks it up really quickly.

I tried trac for a while, but found multi-project support to be a bit of a hack. Bugzilla had usability issues and took ages to set-up. [Basecamp](http://basecamphq.com/) is also really nice, but we wanted something that was hosted our end, rather than in "the cloud".

edit: and I did use OnTime at my last place of employment (the winforms version) - it was nasty to use, everyone found the learning curve rather steep, and at no point did the cost feel justified.

Answer (score 1):

OnTime is too complex and the learning curve is really steep. I suggest redmine. it beats ontime hands down and simple to setup and use.

Comment: I've never found OnTime to be that complicated. There's defects / features and tasks. Once your organisation or software process defines how to use these categorisations then the rest is straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

Well the fact you have to have a paid license for each user of OnTime, versus Redmine which is unlimited users for free.

10-user License $3,995 $3,595/yr
Each Add'l User $499 $449/yr

Man that is a little costly if you ask me.

Answer (score 0):

We're using FogBugz for a project, it's pretty cool. You can register for at free trial to see if it fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the Express version of OnTime isn't suitable for your needs?

It's currently US$5 for 5 users.